# VoidRays vs Stalkers: die or try to retreat?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

In my PvP engagement when I have stalkers+VR vs opponents Stalkers, I often have situation when opponents stalkers are focusing my VRs.

My intuitive wish is to pull VRs back, but quite often opponent can move stalkers and finish VRs...

So I don't get much gain from pulling VRs back: if they stayed and shooted they would do some damage, but when retreating - they just die for nothing. Ok, not really for nothing, my stalkers shooting opponents stalkers, but that is not good consolation.

What is the good micro for such case:

- stay with VR where they are, do damage and die
- or better pull back and try to escape?

Thank you.

Comment: You can always try to hide your VRs before an engagement. But anyway - if you see a Stalker heavy army. Try adding Immortals to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you always want to keep your more expensive units alive. If you know you are going to lose your ground force, run away with the void rays sooner. Void rays are more expensive and take longer to replace than the stalkers you have on the ground. If you can save the void rays to meet up with another stalker army, then you should do so.

In your specific scenario (assuming similar/comparable army size), I would kite the void rays away until all your stalkers are firing on their stalkers. When that occurs, activate Prismatic Alignment and engage their stalker army. The ability will give you a damage boost to your Void Rays so that their stalkers will melt away with the help with the stalkers you have on the ground.